# React: how to dynamically map out images with different file extensions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of items I'm mapping through.  The images are named after the item ID's however I just noticed that not all of them are jpg's.  Two of the images are gifs.  How can I account for those files?

```
   {this.state.items && this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="item-container" key={item.id}>
          <div style={ { backgroundImage: `url("../../images/${item.id}.jpg")` } } className="image-container" key="image">
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution: save the image path:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url("../../images/${item.image}")` }} className="image-container" key="image">
```

Or, if you know the ids, just create a function to get the url, and check for those ids.

OR, a crappy, hack solution that you shouldn't use and will cause a lot of useless network requests, use two background images:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url("../../images/${item.id}.jpg"), url("../../images/${item.id}.gif")`  }} className="image-container" key="image">
```

Example of the css:

```html
<div style="height: 150px; width: 350px; background-image: url(http://doesntExist.com/fake.jpg), url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=second)"/>
```